# Populate Array from List in Model

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have data for the JavaScript function stored in an array. 
Now to make to things easier I was wondering is there a way I can populate a array from the List in Model

I am using an `ASP.NET MVC` framework in backend.

I know there might be some way but i cannot figure it out :(

Comment: Could it be, that with "Database SQL" you meant "Microsoft SQL"?

Comment: @tereško Yeah correct Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: @tereško It would be great if there is some help instead of just editing Sir. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way : have a look on this example. I hope it will help you:
You can create a JavaScript file or put it your view:
You create a `Point View Model` `pointsVM`

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;

  $(function () {
      ko.applyBindings(pointsVM);
       pointsVM.loadPoints();
   });

var pointsVM= {
   Points: ko.observableArray([]),

   loadPoints: function () {
    var self = this;
    //Ajax Call Get All Points
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPath + '/FillIndex',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            self.Articles(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status +" : " + err.statusText);
        }
        });

      }
   };

 function Points(Points) {
   this.field1= ko.observable(Points.field1);
   this.field2= ko.observable(Points.field2);
   this.field3= ko.observable(Points.field3);
   }
```

And In your controller:

```
  public JsonResult FillIndex()
    {
        return Json(db.YourDB.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And in Your View : Just call the javascript Library.

Hope it will help